# ntpd synchronization not working

Tags: ntp, ntpd, raspbian, ntpdate

I'm running latest Raspbian Lite on Raspberry Pi 3 B.
Just reinstalled ntpd completely and it doesn't synchronize time with upstream NTP servers at all.

```
ntpdate -u 0.debian.pool.ntp.org
```

works just fine. Using tcpdump (for eth0 interface) I can see that with ntpdate there are NTP packets going both ways, but with ntpd there is no response from the upstream servers (0...3.debian.pool.ntp.org servers set in ntpd config). When ntpd is running, using ntpq -p I can see:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 0.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.001
 1.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.001
 2.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.001
 3.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.001
```

What may be the source of this problem?

Comment: Indeed, reach = 0 shows that the NTP servers are not reached. Any logs? A day ago someone's chrony server (a better choice than ntpd, by the way) kept exiting because the systemd-timesyncd was already running. Perhaps this is your situation, and ntpd reacts differently.

Comment: Here are the logs from ntpd: https://pastebin.pl/view/c4a8a3c2 Systemd-timesyncd detects ntpd and is not running

Comment: Anyway, installed Chrony and it seems to be working properly...

Comment: I started searching for "soliciting pool servers". Plenty of hits. Glad that chrony fixed it.

Comment: Installing chrony seems to be the right solution. ntp is being abandoned because bugs aren't being fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that your `/etc/ntp.conf` is missing the following section:

```
# Needed for adding pool entries
restrict source notrap nomodify noquery
```

This is part of the default configuration on Debian & Ubuntu, but if you were using a template based on an old version of `ntpd`, it was likely missing.  This is a good example of why it's helpful to keep your configuration as close to the default as possible.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for your reply and answer! Somehow the line you mentioned had got commented out! there was nothing obvious in logs - just refused to sync time and then daemon would go inactive. thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!